# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted open 'C:\angular test\dist\dev\assets\img\Thumbs.db'

Tags: angular, file-permissions

[image: 1]

Initially I was able to run npm start normally. But for some time the following error came up, i can't find out whether it is a permission error or something with my code. But the error is from dist files.

I tried npm cache clean, updating npm,nodejs, running as a admin but none worked for me.

Comment: DId you try to launch the command line as an administrator ?

Comment: yes i tried it..but same result

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.....I had to delete the img file in dist and again tried npm start..then img file was recreated automatically it ran normally....

Answer (score 0):

Close all your programs that can use this file: all file explorer windows, event IDE/Text editors (I've had this issue with Sublime 3). If this doesn't help, try rebooting your system.

Comment: It doesn't help, I tried it....... will it be with windows defender but i could use  it before without errors

Comment: this is pretty common issu in windows system. Try to close all programs that can possibly use filesystem like antiviruses. If this doesn't help, you have an option to load windows in safe mode and delete it there.

Comment: for another angular projects i could run npm start command even the same project without that dist